# How to fetch multiple file formats?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code to fetch pdf files but I want to add a new file format.

For example on this line `elseif ( 1 === preg_match('/w*\.pdf$/i', $item) )` I want to add a m4v file format which I've tried to add it like this elseif `( 1 === preg_match('/w*\.pdf$/i' && '/w*\.m4v$/i', $item) )` which return no error but there is now file to show, or like this `( 1 === preg_match(('/w*\.pdf$/i', $item) && ('/w*\.m4v$/i', $item)) )` which return me this line of error `'bad_response_format'     : 'Bad server response format, try to reload page',`

```
foreach( $items as $item ) {
    if ( ('.' === $item) || ('..' === $item) ) {
    continue;
    }

    if ( is_dir( $targetFolder . '/' . $item ) ) {
        $arr2return['subfolders'][] = $item;
    } elseif ( 1 === preg_match('/w*\.pdf$/i', $item) ) {
        $arr2return['subspdfs'][] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't trust or match filetype by file ending .pdf or .mp4 etc .... better use finfo_file() or SERVER OS functions to determine type of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OR` operator:

```
/\w+\.(pdf|m4v)$/i
```

**Explanation:**

1. `/`: Delimiters of `regex`
2. `\w+`: Match one or more alphanumeric characters
3. `\.`: Matches `.` literal
4. `()`: Capturing group
5. `pdf|m4v`: Matches `pdf` *OR* `m4v`
6. `$`: Ends with
7. `i`: Case-insensitive match

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jE8yY3/2)